# What is the system tray program that takes the current text and edits it in a specific text editor?

Tags: windows, text-editors

On a regular basis, I want to take text from one place (in this case MS Power Query), edit it in a different text editor and then copy it back.

At some point I ran across a program that lived in your system tray that, when you hit a keyboard short cut, take the text in the current window, open it in VIM and then then you quit/save, copy the updated text from  VIM to the original location.

What is this program?

To clarify:
The process with this system tray program using VIM as an example was:

1. You are in your existing program with the text you want edited in another editor
2. You put your cursor in the existing program's text box
3. Hit the keyboard short but
4. The system tray program:

   - Copies the text to a temp text file.
   - Runs VIM pointing to the temp text file
5. you make you're edits in VIM, then Quit save
6. The system tray program:

   - copies the text from the temp text file.
   - pastes is in your existing program
   - deletes the temp text file

Comment: The standard clipboard within Windows isn't enough?

Comment: Is that a question?  :)

Comment: *Yes*, it is indeed a question.  Do you realize how many programs could fit your current description?

Comment: Ok, added a clarification.  I don't there there to many of these programs.

Comment: An OSX version of what in want in Windows: http://onethingwell.org/post/619604425/quickcursor

Comment: Found it: http://www.listary.com/text-editor-anywhere

Comment: If you know the answer, you might want to post it _as an answer_ while you still can (i.e., before the question gets closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: [text edit anywhere](http://www.listary.com/text-editor-anywhere)

Text Editor Anywhere allows you to edit text anywhere with your favorite text editor. It provides a means of taking advantages of some advanced features (like auto-completing, spell checking and syntax highlighting) that are only available in an external text editor. It may also save you from web browser crashes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: In principle I agree but in this case, since I'm pointing to a specific (but small) tool, I think this is correct.